# Using erase/remove idiom on a class that holds an object of a class whose copy constructor and assignment operator have been deleted

Tags: c++

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class B
{
public:
    B() = default;
    B(const B&) = delete;
    B& operator=(const B&) = delete;
};

class A
{
public:
    A(int i) :
        data(i)
    {
    }

    bool operator==(const A& rhs)
    {
        return rhs.data == data;
    }

    B b;
    int data = 0;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> as;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        as.push_back(A{i});
    }
    //remove std::moves all the items to be removed at the 
    //end of the vector and returns an iterator begining at 
    //the first item to be removed. Erase then removes those
    //items.
    as.erase(std::remove(as.begin(), as.end(), as[6]), as.end());//Fails because 
    //A stores instance of B
}
```

I encountered this problem when I was making a snake game. I have a `Segment` and a `Snake` class. `Snake` stores a vector of `Segment`s. `Segment` has its copy constructor and assignment operator deleted because I don't want to be able to copy individual segments (or infact snake as well) but I am forced to not delete them just so I can remove a segment at any index location from the snake. Is there any way to get around this problem?

Comment: `vector.push_back` and `vector.erase` require the items to be copy or movable, and A isn't.

Comment: disabling copy construction and assignment also disables move construction and assignment. You could add the move special member functions back in and carry on.

Comment: Have you looked at move semantics?

Comment: Move semantics was the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `as.emplace_back(i);` so you wouldn't make use of `B`'s copy constructor.

https://godbolt.org/z/TMs7eoobh